# Android Google Maps V2, How do I show comerical places on the map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Google map on my application which at the moment shows services on the map like rail station and church etc. However unlike Google Maps (the official one), my one does not show commercial places in the area like McDonalds, Boots, Subway and Starbucks etc. etc.

I tried to research if this is something I must set on my map but could not find anything, **can anyone tell me how to show commercial places on the map**

Many thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) to show Points of interest

To use Place API in Android, you can read it [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1)